# Is it my computer's fault that I can't connect to the internet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a connection problem I can't solve, and I'm in Korea so there's a language-barrier regarding tech-support. If this question is inappropriate for this site, let me know and I will move it.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad, running Windows 7. My neighbor and I share internet, and I can connect to her iptime router. However, I have no internet connection even though I'm connected to the network. I can connect if I go over to her apartment and plug the cable into my laptop, and everyone else can connect to it and get internet. I've also power-cycled the whole system, reset the router and modem, and done a system-restore to a time before I installed some updates.

This happened about 1 month ago, before the problem solved itself, but it has happened again. I'm sure that's more than you care to know, so tell me what kind of detailed info about my system I should supply. Thank you!

Comment: Check if you have a static IP set. In Windows, static IPs are set for an interface, and wireless and wired are usually different interfaces. If you have a static IP that conflicts with another on the network, or you're using the wrong subnet or gateway, then it won't work - the easiest way is to just switch it to automatic (DHCP).

Comment: I have "Obtain an IP address automatically" set for both IPv6 and IPv4 - which I assume is what you're referring to?

Comment: Yea. At least that part seems fine.

Comment: There's a vague possibility it's a DNS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've probably called tech-support and have already double or triple checked your cables.

We'll need a few things:

1. Name and model of the wireless router.
2. Name and model of the modem
3. Is the cable you plug in to that can access internet coming from the wireless router, or from the modem?
4. What do the other internet users connect to for their internet?
5. Modem's IP address and routers IP address

After you have all that, plug in to the connection that you can access internet from AND connect to the wireless router and follow these instructions:

1. Press the windows key or click start.
2. Type 'cmd.exe' without the '' and press enter.
3. Type 'ipconfig /all' without the '' and press enter.
4. Copy the output and paste it here

If you are plugging into the router itself and getting internet, then the router is the issue, I would check to make sure the router is configured to 'hand out' ip addresses via DHCP AND has a range of addresses configured (192.168.0.1-192.168.0.254).

Comment: My school's tech-support man just now made a personal visit to my apartment. He changed some settings in the router, which I couldn't figure out because it was all in Korean. From what I saw over his shoulder, it looked like he made the changes you suggested in your final paragraph. Thank you for your help!